# Sharepoint - Link 2 columns to autocomplete

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I have a list in Sharepoint that has 2 columns. "Name" and "Surname". Then I have another list which lists information about employees which also have those 2 columns with lookup to the previous ones.

I want that, when, in this list, you select a name in the "Name" column, the "Surname" column next to it immediately complete with the associate Surname listed in the first list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio to do this, [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff717837.aspx)

To do using SharePoint itself. (If you have already mentioned "Name" Column as a look up field/column)

- Go to "List setting" from "List Tools">"List".
- In the "Columns" section you will see your "Name" lookup column,
  Click on it.
- In "Additional Column Settings" , Tick "Surname" Checkbox. Click OK.

Now you will have your "Surname" column auto generated.